# How to get secret from AWS parameter store in dockerRegistry feature in TeamCity Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, teamcity, aws-ssm

Teamcity IaC in kotlin has a built in feature to connect to docker registry

```
params {
    param("teamcity.ui.settings.readOnly", "true")
    
    param("artifactory.user", "myUserName")
    password("artifactory.password", "credentialsJSON:XXXXXXX", display = ParameterDisplay.HIDDEN)        
}

 features {
    dockerRegistry {
        id = "%artifactory.registry.id%"
        name = "My Project API docker registry"
        url = "%artifactory.url%"
        userName = "%artifactory.user%"
        password = "%artifactory.password%"
    }
```

currently artifactory.password have it stored as credentialsJSON in Teamcity

I have some build steps in which I can populate the parameters from AWS parameter store (using scripts / custom extension) - but this feature triggers at project level and before any build steps are run, so if I set it to blank to be populated later in build steps gives an error for artifactory login before any build steps have started

- what are my options if I want to retrieve artifactory.password from AWS parameter store and pass it in here ?

Comment: Have you found a way to access the credentialsJSON from Kotlin?

Comment: no, not for this use case - it has to start somewhere so some stuff has to remain in TeamCity params - instead of AWS, I checked with other teams here, everyone is just using the root project level params for artifactory